# Textures get blurred when zoomed in Opengl ES 10. How do I fix it?

Tags: android, image, opengl-es, blur

I've been trying to draw a bitmap, reading from a file onto the canvas using OPENGL ES 1.0. When zooming in using the glTranslatef(), the image tends to get blurred. I've looked it up almost for a day, but couldn't solve this issue.

Things I've tried :

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST); 
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_NEAREST); 
gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
```

Adjusting the Near and Far planes :

```
GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 1000.0f);
```

Nothing, seems to help. I want to image to zoom uniformly without quality loss.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what exactly you expect, and what you're seeing? The texture image obviously has limited resolution. If you zoom in too close, you will either get very large pixels when sampling with `GL_NEAREST`, or a very blurry image when sampling with `GL_LINEAR`. You can't possibly get a nice looking image at high zoom levels if your original image data does not have sufficient resolution to allow that. Based on your description, it's not clear to me if you have a problem in your code, or if your expectations are unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

`GL_NICEST` has never been a valid value for `GL_TEXTURE_(MIN|MAX)_FILTER` or `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_(S|T)`.

You're looking for `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` (if you provide mipmaps, `GL_LINEAR` if you don't) and `GL_LINEAR` for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` and `GL_TEXTURE_MAX_FILTER` and `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` or `GL_REPEAT` for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_(S|T)`.